# Unable to post on user wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am kind of confused right now because I can't figure out what could be possible wrong with the following code since its not working.

```
require 'facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(

  'appId'  => 'myapplicationid',
  'secret' => 'myapplicationsecret',
));

$attachment = array(
        'access_token'=> "user access token",
        'message' => "Message Goes Here",
        'name' => 'Title goes here',
        'caption' => "some text",
        'link' => 'https://apps.facebook.com/somelink/',
        'description' => 'some description',
        'picture' => "http://example.com/test.jpg"
        );
try {
// Proceed knowing you have a user who is logged in and authenticated
    $result = $facebook->api("/$userid/feed/",'post',$attachment);
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
error_log($e);
//$user = null;
}
```

At the time of authenticating and getting the access token i got the following permissions from the user email,publish_stream,publish_actions. I think publish_stream is the one required into to push a wall post. Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please Update with error that you are getting?

Comment: That's the whole point it doesn't give any error nor does it post :S

Comment: have you tried doing a var_dump of the $result variable so you can see if the facebook api is returning anything?

Comment: Ok i am not sure how to use var_dump but i simply tried var_dump($result); underneth $result it didn't display anything and there is no error_log either because i think the godaddy hosting doesn't have that for some odd reason.

Comment: I also tried to echo var_dump($result) and print_r($result) still didn't get any output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is most likely because the PHP SDK using the application access token and overriding the access token you place. Try explicitly setting it with

`$facebook->setAccessToken('USER_ACCESS_TOKEN');`

Also var_dump or print your error (`$e`) if your hosting company doesn't give it.

(Also error logs are available)

[image: Error Logs]

Comment: Ok great now it works! Thank you so much! Can you kindly also guide me how to get Long Term Access Token for the user because supposedly that was the issue. The Access Token had expired

Comment: Just to add I am using GRAPH API method not the PHP SDK method to get access token at the moment

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
            . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page) . "&scope=email,publish_stream,publish_actions";

Comment: Nevermind the Facebook manual helped! Thanks a lot for pointing in the right direction